# How to see the content of an API in the browser which needs authentication

Tags: android, json, api, github-api

I'm developing an Android project which needs to access a `github API`, [this api](https://api.github.com/user/repos) contains all the `user repositories`. Before programming Android, I want to see what's in this API, in Android I know that I need to supply the `credentials` in the `HTTP header`, but how can I see the content in the `browser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

[Advanced rest client for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snmba.restclient&hl=fr)

Comment: Hi, I want to view it in the browser of the computer. You know which tool to use?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: Google chrome app for web browser ;)

Comment: Great, I installed it, do you know how to set the header?

Comment: Enter a URL, select GET and enter your header in the paragraph. Then you press send. Did you open the app before asking the question? lol